# How do I change Korn(ksh) version dynamically based on platform?

Tags: shell, unix, posix, ksh, shebang

I wanted to use the `/usr/bin/ksh93` interpreter on AIX and Linux wherever possible but switch to `/usr/bin/ksh` where it's not applicable like Mac OS X and wanted the script to be universally compatible in unix. I don't think there is any fallback mechanism in shebang

Comment: Now you want to create portable scripts? Use she-bang #!/bin/sh and use only the common minimum of shells (eg dash is an example of minimalistic shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ksh` and `sh` have some syntax in common, you can prefix the start of the
script with a test for ksh or ksh93 in the PATH and rerun the script with
the right interpreter. Replace the #! with the pathname to sh. (Hopefully
it is the same on both machines, or you are back where you started. You can
still try `#!/usr/bin/env sh` if your env will find the path for you). Add:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$DONEIT" != true ]
then export DONEIT=true # avoid recursion
     if command -v ksh > /dev/null 2>&1
     then    exec ksh   $0 "$@"
     else    exec ksh93 $0 "$@"
     fi
fi
... rest of your script ...
```

Note: `command -v` is the POSIX way for finding a command's path.

(Often in these situations, at the installation of a package a script goes
through the #! files and updates the interpreter path to that needed by the
target machine).

Alternatively, you could replace the `#!` line by any fixed path you control, eg `#!/home/user/myksh`, and link that file to the right ksh.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a symbolic links.

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/ksh93 ]; then
   ln -s /usr/bin/ksh93 /usr/bin/localksh 
else
   ln -s /usr/bin/ksh /usr/bin/localksh 
fi
```

The shebang will be `#!/usr/bin/localksh`.
I would prefer using a normal shebang `#!/bin/ksh`, but when that one already exists and is the wrong version you will be stuck.